# how to iterate rows of one column to get a new column without using for loop in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one column called Date which is of object type having both date and time in the form '2019/10/07,12:44:58'.
I have tried slicing out the date part from this Date column then convert this to the proper date format. I want to apply this function on the date column to create a new column called date1 without using for loop.

Comment: Use `data['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], format= '%Y/%m/%d').dt.date`

Comment: Its showing error as "unknown string format"

Comment: edited my comment, you have to specify the `format`

Comment: again error is coming as "ValueError: time data 2019/10/07,12:45:03 doesn't match format specified"

Comment: Please just look at the error, it shows what the problem is.. `format='%Y/%m/%s,%H:%M:%S'`

Comment: In my dataset there is a comma in between the date and time, I guess thats why error is coming. Can you solve this error?

Comment: Yes man, I have seen that, As i have said my dataset has a comma in between thats why this code is not working . Its a different format
Can you see the comma ?  '%Y/%m/%s,%H:%M:%S'
so can you provide solution for this one?

Comment: Your data has different formats, the comma is not the problem. Look at the first two rows, the data is different from the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we can see, the first two rows have a different date format. So we convert the rest to datetime first with `errors='coerce'`. Then we convert the first two rows and use `fillna`, to get both dates together:

```
date1 = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], format='%Y/%m/%d,%H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')
date2 = pd.to_datetime(data.loc[date1.isna(), 'Date'], format='%d-%m-%Y,%H:%M:%S')

data['Date'] = date1.fillna(date2)

                 Date     Open     High      Low    Close   Qty  Value(Lk)  \
0 2019-10-07 12:45:17  1208.65  1208.85  1208.40  1208.85  1125      13.60   
1 2019-10-07 12:45:00  1208.70  1209.10  1208.40  1209.10  9344     112.95   
2 2019-10-07 12:43:58  1208.80  1209.40  1208.35  1208.65  7342      88.75   
3 2019-10-07 12:42:58  1208.70  1209.20  1208.40  1209.00  9355     113.08   
4 2019-10-07 12:41:57  1208.75  1209.00  1207.80  1208.35  5890      71.17   

   Trades BS  
0       4     
1      15     
2      13     
3      15     
4      13
```

Original data:

```
                  Date     Open     High      Low    Close   Qty  Value(Lk)  \
0  07-10-2019,12:45:17  1208.65  1208.85  1208.40  1208.85  1125      13.60   
1  07-10-2019,12:45:00  1208.70  1209.10  1208.40  1209.10  9344     112.95   
2  2019/10/07,12:43:58  1208.80  1209.40  1208.35  1208.65  7342      88.75   
3  2019/10/07,12:42:58  1208.70  1209.20  1208.40  1209.00  9355     113.08   
4  2019/10/07,12:41:57  1208.75  1209.00  1207.80  1208.35  5890      71.17   

   Trades BS  
0       4     
1      15     
2      13     
3      15     
4      13
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, can you explain me the significance of pd.to_datetime(data.loc[date1.isna(), 'Date'])